# Dictionary becomes BaseList in MongoEngine after assignement

Tags: python, dictionary, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine **0.9.0**

```
class EntityChange(Document):
    ...
    old_data = DictField()
    new_data = DictField()
```

I want to save `dict` objects into `old_data` and `new_data`.

Why are fields becoming `BaseList` after assignment?

```
data = {u'int_id': 100500, u'_cls': 'BuildingKind', ...}
instance = EntityChange()
instance.new_data = data
# after that
# isinstance(instance, BaseList) is True
# isinstance(instance, BaseDict) is False
# instance.new_data == ['int_id', 'id', ...] is True. why?
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `isinstance(instance.new_data, BaseDict)` and `type(instance.new_data)`, and the output of `instance.new_data` (leave out the comparison)

Comment: @NilsWerner, Sure. It's for 0.9.0
`isinstance(instance.new_data, BaseDict): False
type(instance.new_data): <class 'mongoengine.base.datastructures.BaseList'>
instance.new_data: ['id', 'ent_id', 'int_id', 'type', '_cls']`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, can you create am [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also check whats up with `BuildingKind`. Maybe setting the `_cls` attribute is the culprit.

Comment: I'm actually using flask-mongoengine wrapper.
https://github.com/oriontvv/mongoengine_MCVE here you can get mcve.
just exec `docker-compose up --build`. One interesting thing. `_cls` field of `new_data` requires the existence of model BuildingKind. It's really very strange.

Comment: I don't exactly see a Docker image as MCVE... And [that `_cls` thing is a known bug and has been fixed in 0.10.1](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1058).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Passing a `dict` containing `_cls` or `_types` triggered a bug in mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1058).

[A fix has been submitted](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/commit/903982e8967bef1f119eaa54cdec5b2725d3dabb) and was merged in versions 0.10.1 and later.

Comment: Thanks, updating to 0.10.1 fixes behaviour.